# Technique behind the way google earth overlaps polygons on top of pictures

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What´s the technique behind the way google earth overlaps polygons on top of pictures(like the ones users assign to streets and houses) ?

It seems to be aware of perspective, and I don´t remember seeing it covered on books on computer vision.

Thanks,

Rafael

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you mean how does Google Earth automatically convert satellite imagery to vector polygons, or do you mean something else? In general there's an enormous amount of sophisticated computer vision algorithms and research in Google Earth, it's one of the most technically insane Google's products.

Comment: No, I mean how Google Earth analyses pictures(like 360 degrees pictures) that are attributed to locations by the users. When one passes the mouse over, it generates(or brings from cache) a polygon(usually distorted rectangles) that are in almost exact alignment with the objects in the scene. For instance if there´s a wall on the scene, and the picture was taken from the bottom left, there will be a rectangle directed upwards to the right. If the picture was taken from the top right, there will be a rectangle pointing downward from the left. It´s seems to "get" which lines are important..

Comment: ... and this totally blows me over! I agree it´s technically insane. I just want to know if the result of their research is available.

Comment: Generating a polygon aligned with an image shouldn't be a terribly hard problem. Search for "edge detection" first, then for "object detection" etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out edge detection, I think that is what I am looking for. What I knew about object detection alone was not enough for the perspective aspect of the problem.